# How to compute a summary by group with dplyr with a function that takes a matrix as argument

Tags: r, function, matrix, dplyr, pipeline

I'm evaluating the test-retest reliability of a questionnaire. 
I've got more than 200 pairs of variables (nominal, ordinal, or numeric), each measured at test and retest, for whom I compute a concordance statistic and its bootstrapped confidence interval.

I managed to create a function to obtain the 3 computations (estimation, lower and upper bound) for each pairs in a single step but I struggle to creating one allowing me to group the results by supplementary variables.

Because I'll need to plot the results, I would like eventually a dataframe output.

For simplicity, I made a toy example of 8 variables in a dataframe called dfSO

```
dput(dfSO)  
structure(list(qordi1T = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("Je n'ai pas de médecin de médecin généraliste attitré", 
"Moins d'un an", "1 à 2 ans", "2 à 5 ans", "Plus de 5 ans"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), qordi2T = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("Mauvaise", "Passable", 
"Bonne", "Très bonne", "Excellente"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), qnum1T = c(70L, 90L, 90L, 100L, 100L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 50L, 
40L, 100L, 100L, 75L, 75L, 95L, 40L), qnum2T = c(100L, 85L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 85L, 100L, 70L, 100L, 100L, 95L, 75L, 
100L, 80L), qnomi1T = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Oui", "Non"), class = "factor"), 
    qnomi2T = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Oui", "Non"), class = "factor"), 
    proT = structure(c(7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 
    7L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Agriculteur exploitant", 
    "Artisan, commerçant, chef d'entreprise", "Cadre ou profession intellectuelle supérieure :- Profession libérale et assimilée- Cadre de la fonction publique- Profession intellectuelle et artistique- Cadre d'entreprise et ingénieur", 
    "Employé :- de la fonction publique- administratif d'entreprise- de commerce- Personnel de services directs aux particuliers", 
    "Ouvrier :- qualifié de type industriel, artisanal, de la manutention, du magasinage et du transport, chauffeurs- non qualifié de type industriel et artisanal- agricole", 
    "Profession intermédiaire :- de l'enseignement, de la santé, de la fonction publique et assimilés- administrative et commerciales des entreprises- Technicien- Contremaître, agent de maîtrise", 
    "N/A"), class = "factor"), sexT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Femme", 
    "Homme"), class = "factor"), qordi1RT = structure(c(5L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("Je n'ai pas de médecin de médecin généraliste attitré", 
    "Moins d'un an", "1 à 2 ans", "2 à 5 ans", "Plus de 5 ans"
    ), class = c("ordered", "factor")), qordi2RT = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Mauvaise", "Passable", "Bonne", "Très bonne", 
    "Excellente"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), qnum1RT = c(67L, 
    87L, 88L, 100L, 94L, 79L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 55L, 100L, 99L, 
    88L, 70L, 89L, 18L), qnum2RT = c(98L, 89L, 99L, 100L, 81L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 77L, 63L, 99L, 98L, 71L, 100L, 100L
    ), qnomi1RT = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Oui", "Non"), class = "factor"), 
    qnomi2RT = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Oui", "Non"), class = "factor"), 
    proRT = structure(c(7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("Agriculteur exploitant", 
    "Artisan, commerçant, chef d'entreprise", "Cadre ou profession intellectuelle supérieure :- Profession libérale et assimilée- Cadre de la fonction publique- Profession intellectuelle et artistique- Cadre d'entreprise et ingénieur", 
    "Employé :- de la fonction publique- administratif d'entreprise- de commerce- Personnel de services directs aux particuliers", 
    "Ouvrier :- qualifié de type industriel, artisanal, de la manutention, du magasinage et du transport, chauffeurs- non qualifié de type industriel et artisanal- agricole", 
    "Profession intermédiaire :- de l'enseignement, de la santé, de la fonction publique et assimilés- administrative et commerciales des entreprises- Technicien- Contremaître, agent de maîtrise", 
    "N/A"), class = "factor"), sexRT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Femme", 
    "Homme"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are 2 ordinal variables, 4 nominal  and 2 numeric, each measured at test (T) and retest (RT)

```
> str(dfSO)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ qordi1T : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "Je n'ai pas de médecin de médecin généraliste attitré"<..: 5 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 ...
 $ qordi2T : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "Mauvaise"<"Passable"<..: 3 3 2 4 4 4 1 2 1 3 ...
 $ qnum1T  : int  70 90 90 100 100 70 80 100 50 40 ...
 $ qnum2T  : int  100 85 100 100 100 100 100 85 100 70 ...
 $ qnomi1T : Factor w/ 2 levels "Oui","Non": 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ qnomi2T : Factor w/ 2 levels "Oui","Non": 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ proT    : Factor w/ 7 levels "Agriculteur exploitant",..: 7 7 5 7 5 7 4 7 1 6 ...
 $ sexT    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Femme","Homme": 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ qordi1RT: Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "Je n'ai pas de médecin de médecin généraliste attitré"<..: 5 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 ...
 $ qordi2RT: Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "Mauvaise"<"Passable"<..: 3 4 1 4 4 5 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ qnum1RT : int  67 87 88 100 94 79 100 100 50 55 ...
 $ qnum2RT : int  98 89 99 100 81 100 100 100 100 77 ...
 $ qnomi1RT: Factor w/ 2 levels "Oui","Non": 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ qnomi2RT: Factor w/ 2 levels "Oui","Non": 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ proRT   : Factor w/ 7 levels "Agriculteur exploitant",..: 7 7 5 4 7 7 4 7 1 6 ...
 $ sexRT   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Femme","Homme": 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
```

To compute the concordance statistic on qualitative variable, the **rel::gac** function takes **as input a matrix** with n subjects and two observations (n*2 matrix)

I made the following function to extract Gwet AC2 (quadratic ponderation) estimations and its bootstrapped CI for ordered variables

```
library("rel")
library("boot")

ordiTF <- sapply(dfSO[, 1:8], is.ordered)
ordi <- which(ordiTF == TRUE)

g <- function(data, x)
  gac(data[x, c(1, 2)], weight = "quadratic", conf.level = 1-(0.05/8))[[5]]

offset <- 8
B <- 500  
item <- c()
est <- c()
lci <- c()
uci <- c()
for (i in ordi) {
  item <- c(item, i)
  est <- c(est, gac(data = dfSO[ , c(i, i + offset)], weight = "quadratic", conf.level = 1-(0.05/8))[[5]])
  b <- boot(dfSO[ ,c(i, i + offset)], g, B)
  lci <- c(lci, boot.ci(b, type = "bca")$bca[4])
  uci <- c(uci, boot.ci(b, type = "bca")$bca[5])
}
data.frame(item = item, est = est, lci = lci, uci = uci)
```

What I would like now, is to compute this statistic for each pairs **by a third variable**, say 'sex'. 
I'll begin with grouping by this variable, but then I'm not able anymore to specify the columns adequately.

For example, if I want to compute AC2 between ordi1 at test and retest **by sex** *with dplyr*, I don't know anymore how to specify these variables.
I tried different options, among which:

```
dfSO %>% 
  group_by(sexT) %>% 
  select(sexT, qordi1T, qordi1RT) %$%
  gac(as.matrix(qordi1T, qordi1RT), weight = "quadratic")[[5]]
```

But none of them did the job

As a non-english native speaker, my first limitation to answer this pb is my difficulty to google it, and I'm aware that this question might have been already asked, but if so, I wasn't able to find it.

Thanks for your time and for your help

**Folowing @42 remarks, I made several edits**

Regarding the **boot** issue, I'm not sure to understand what's wrong with my syntax, so I'll begin with my initial problem

1. Error output

Here is the error output I obtained

```
    > dfSO %>% 
    +     group_by(sexT) %>% 
    +     select(sexT, qordi1T, qordi1RT) %$%
    +     gac(as.matrix(qordi1T, qordi1RT), weight = "quadratic")[[5]]

    Error in gac(as.matrix(qordi1T, qordi1RT), weight = "quadratic") : 
      The data frame needs to be formatted as a n*2 matrix!
```

2. I made a wrong copy-paste in my initial code, copying a desperate attempt to use **%$%** instead of **%>%** (that's what I meant saying "none of them did the job"). It should have been

```
    dfSO %>% 
        group_by(sexT) %>% 
        select(sexT, qordi1T, qordi1RT) %>%
        gac(as.matrix(qordi1T, qordi1RT), weight = "quadratic")
```

with the same error

```
    Error in gac(., as.matrix(qordi1T, qordi1RT), weight = "quadratic") : 
      The data frame needs to be formatted as a n*2 matrix!
```

Note that the quoting in gac() doesn't suppress the error

```
    dfSO %>% 
        group_by(sexT) %>% 
        select(sexT, qordi1T, qordi1RT) %>%
        gac(as.matrix('qordi1T', 'qordi1RT'), weight = "quadratic")
```

```
Error in gac(., as.matrix("qordi1T", "qordi1RT"), weight = "quadratic") : 
  The data frame needs to be formatted as a n*2 matrix!
```

3. While everything goes find without grouping

```
    dfSO %>%
        select(qordi1T, qordi1RT) %>%
        gac(as.matrix('qordi1T', 'qordi1RT'), weight = "quadratic")
```

```
    Call:
    gac(data = ., kat = as.matrix("qordi1T", "qordi1RT"), weight = "quadratic")

          Estimate   StdErr  LowerCB UpperCB
    Const 0.860780 0.097708 0.652520   1.069

    Confidence level = 95%
    Sample size = 16
```

4. Finally, using magrittr::extract2() allows one to extract the estimation (replace the **[[5]]** part of the **g** function)

```
    dfSO %>% 
      select(qordi1T, qordi1RT) %>%
      gac(as.matrix('qordi1T', 'qordi1RT'), weight = "quadratic") %>% 
      extract2('est')
```

```
        Const 
    0.8607799
```

5. Now, back to my grouping issue. As I group by a third variable, I'm not able to compute the coefficient for each of its level (see edit #2). I believe that the problem lies in the fact that **gac()** takes as input a matrix and not a dataframe.

Ideally, I would like to obtain a dataframe like this

```
    > AC2_ordi_bySexT
      item  SexT       AC2    AC2_lci   AC2_uci
    1    1 Homme 0.6551724  0.4182536 0.9832149
    2    2 Homme 1.0000000 -0.4163015 0.9023788
    3    1 Femme 0.8734663  0.5308729 0.9780148
    4    2 Femme 0.4605954 -0.3208255 0.9073359
```

6. So what I would like is to adapt my **g** function in order to obtain a dataframe like this for each grouping variable (sex, age, ...)
7. Finally, I edited my title question. I hope it now fits better its content.

Comment: I get no error. There is no indication of what was expected. There is no apparent connection with the title of the question. "Didn't do the job" is not helpful in understanding what the "job" might be. The impression I get from the code is that you do not know how to use `boot`, but how that relates to your title or your expectations is not clear. The `g` function you define does not have an indexing parameter. Read the section in `?boot` about the "statistic" parameter more carefully.

Comment: @42 Thank you for your time. I made several edits in order to address some of your comments.